# BSF Assertion from script file does not load UDVs

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to use groovy scripts as BSF assertion in JMeter. The script written inside the JMETER assertion script box works well, but when I try to use it through a groovy file it is not loading the User Defined Variables it needs for assertions

It says

```
org.apache.bsf.BSFException: exception from Groovy: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: mobileNumber class: D__RESTAPITesting_JmeterBSFAssertionScripts_Script1
```

Not sure why it is looking for property when ${..} refers to a variable (if I am not wrong). Any help on the error message and how to use a script file for assertions ?

The scripts I have written are saved as *.groovy. Do I need to save scripts in some other extensions for BSF to read it correctly ?

Comment: Not that it solves your issue or anything, but you should always prefer using a JSR223 step over a BSF step.  I think BSF is an older implementation of the newer JSR223?

Comment: Yes you are right. I am shifting from BSF to JSR223. But dont't know if we have any automated technique to do that. i.e. I have test plans with around 150 BSF (Assertions/post-/pre-processors). Dont want to invest time in changing each an every BSF to JSR of them manually until and unless we have any functional blocker (like Apache stops having BSF in further releases...). So the task is having a low priority right now.

Comment: Yep, no need to refactor what already had worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass your User Defined Variables via Parameters input like `${foo} ${bar}`
2. In your .groovy script body refer variables as `args[0] args[1]`

See image below for details (the solution works fine for file inputs as well) and [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for advanced information on using JMeter's assertions.

[image]

Comment: In my case I will be using almost all (more than 10) UDVs
I see script box is using some variable - "vars" . Any way I can use the vars object so that I can get access to all the UDVs